# Keyboard simulation fail

Tags: c, arrays, winapi, random, keyboard

I am making a program and i need it to type a random letter from an array. This is how i tried to do it:

```
{
srand ( time(NULL) );
WORD arrayNum[4] = {0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44};
int RandIndex = rand() % 4;

INPUT ip;
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 0;
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip.ki.wVk = arrayNum; 
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; 
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; 
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

I must say i am new with this and i don't really know what should i do. The error i get says:

```
invalid conversion from 'WORD* {aka short unsigned int*}' to 'WORD {aka short unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]
```

This confuses me a lot..

Comment: Calling [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) consecutively with an *nInputs* parameter of `1` completely defies its purpose. You could just continue using [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx) and suffer from the very issues that `SendInput` set out to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is in this line:

```
ip.ki.wVk = arrayNum;
```

Here, the `wVk` field [is supposed to be a `WORD` representing the virtual key code to send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271(v=vs.85).aspx). However, you've assigned it `arrayNum`, which is an *array* of `WORD`s. Based on your code, I think you meant

```
ip.ki.wVk = arrayNum[RandIndex];
```

since you weren't using `RandIndex` anywhere. Going forward, I'd recommend compiling with the warning level turned all the way up, since it probably would have flagged the non-use of `RandIndex` in the code.

(Also, if you do ask more questions on Stack Overflow, please try to include more information about the error message. I had to look up the docs to determine which line that particular error occurred on. It's a lot easier for people to help out if they can see the specific line where things went wrong.)

Comment: And this only works as shown because the virtual key codes `VK_A`..`VK_D` *happen* to have the same numeric values as ASCII characters `A`..`D`. When sending text with `SendInput()`, you should consider sending actual Unicode characters using the `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the actual array itself to `wVk` when you should be passing a specific element of the array instead:

```
ip.ki.wVk = arrayNum[RandIndex];
```

That being said, I would suggest using the `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag when sending text characters with `SendInput()`, don't use virtual key codes.  And you should pass 2 `INPUT` structures in one call to `SendInput()`, like @IInspectable suggested. Don't call `SendInput()` twice for each `INPUT`, that defeats some of the benefits of using  `SendInput()`:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
LPCWSTR chars = L"ABCD";
int RandIndex = rand() % 4;

INPUT ip[2];
memset(ip, 0, sizeof(ip));

ip[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip[0].ki.wScan = (WORD) chars[RandIndex]; 
ip[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;

memcpy(&ip[1], &ip[0], sizeof(INPUT));
ip[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; 

SendInput(2, ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```